# Design studio for mockups and UX designer, iOS, process

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-experience

I just got a new gig with a startup, they have a design studio that creates mock ups in photoshop and then sends them to me ( I am the UX designer ). Now they started talking to me about a process of defining how many pixels are needed for the dimensions of every png and jpeg and all the other mockups and installing photoshop on my machine, so I can figure out the dimensions when I open the psd files.

To me it sounds normal for the design studio to give me some assets and provide a file with every asset and its dimensions ( as in, this is an icon, size is (46x80), as opposed to me opening the asset in psd and figuring that out myself.

I was wondering what do other companies do? What is the process in place between the mock up design studio and the actual UX programmer who translates those assets into actual screens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "standard".  It's generally best to let the designers provide individual files since they're the Photoshop experts and may be tweaking the images over time. You may have to provide them a list of files with descriptions, format, size, and variations (enabled, disabled, active). We ask for retina sizes and then have a tool to generate non-retina ones.

We like to use Google spreadsheets for the list of files and DropBox for the actual transfer.

Having said that, you should have Photoshop and learn to use it because there will be times where a graphic needs a tweak and you don't want to wait on someone else.

Answer (score 0):

So who is actually designing the experience? Is it your job to code it? Or, are you the guy that is supposed to come up with the wireframes and then them do the visual design according to that?

Comment: no I am the guy coding it, some other team is building the png's and other stuff.

Comment: Oh, in that case it could go either way. I do the wire frames, the visual design as well. In some cases I've been asked to slice up and just send over images. Others the developer would rather slice it up as they see fit.

Answer (score 0):

With the company I work at (and in my freelance work) I'm rarely given the exact sizing of any assets, unless there's a specific requirement.

For the most part, when building a new site (or amending an existing one), I don't find out the sizes of anything until I open up Photoshop and start cropping.